# Is there any sort of "Codelet Template" in KDevelop?

Tags: c++, ide, code-completion, kdevelop, code-templates

Everytime I need to input a piece of code such as "switch .. case" or "declaring a class", I desire a way I can rapidly achieve it by hitting a shortcut.

In many IDEs, we can do it by pressing some shortcut keys, and IDEs will paste  a little piece of pre-defined code at the position of the focuse.

Is there any similar way in KDevelop?
I'm not meaning the File/Project Templates here.

Thanks!

Comment: Certainly there are some kind of third party snippet plugins but questions to help to find such are off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, use the 'Snippets' plugin distributed with Kate.

1. Install the Kate editor. Several of the plugins included can also be used in KDevelop; there's been some discussion of distributing those separately but it hasn't happened yet.
2. In KDevelop, use the menu `Window -> Add Tool View` and select 'Snippets'.
3. There will be a 'Snippets' toolview. Click on entries to paste them, or you can bind a shortcut. You can add new entries and categories.

[image]